# Printing RIds of Vertices created during oetl.sh

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-etl

I'm wondering if it is possible to print the rids of vertices's created during the oetl.sh script, I felt it might help in faster creation of Edges from Java code.

Comment: please can you let me know the reason for downvote, I couldn't see any questions or documentation to retrieve and print document level information in orientDB ETL tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for example

```
"transformers": [
            { "vertex": { "class": "yourVertex" } },
            { "code":   { "language": "Javascript", "code": "print('Current record: ' + record.getIdentity());" } }
        ],
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful

Comment: You can use also record.field('yourProperty')